# css issue, outer div does not get inner ones' height

Tags: css, html

Please solve that mystery to me..

I'm having the simplest layout of webform, meaning - header,content, and footer.
I've placed some div inside the content div which suppose to contain flyout menu. Now the content div does not get the height of the menu's div, as if it is not it's son. However, the menu div do get the content's div right and left borders.
I check with the 'inspect element' tool and the height of the content's div is 0.
Why? why? why does the menu's div is not considered the son of the content's div.

here is some scripts:

```
<body>
    <form id="formMaster" runat="server">
    <div id="header">
        bla bla
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div>
            <ucCatMenu:MenuControl ID="CatMenu" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        bla bla
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

here is the menu's web user control code (a bit long, I just paste it all):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="wucCategoriesMenu.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="Controls_wucCategoriesMenu" %>
<style type="text/css">
    /* ================================================================ 
This copyright notice must be untouched at all times.

The original version of this stylesheet and the associated (x)html
is available at http://www.cssmenus.co.uk
Copyright (c) 2009- Stu Nicholls. All rights reserved.
This stylesheet and the associated (x)html may be modified in any 
way to fit your requirements.
=================================================================== */


    #flyout
    {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 3px 0px 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 180px;
        float: right;
        position: relative;
    }

    #flyout ul
    {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        left: -9999px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 180px;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #flyout table
    {
        margin: -1px -10px;
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    #flyout li
    {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        float: left;
    }
    #flyout li a
    {
        background: rgb(136, 136, 136);
        width: 170px;
        height: 24px;
        text-align: right;
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        line-height: 24px; /*padding-right: 10px;*/
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        text-decoration: none;
        float: left;
        display: block;
    }
    #flyout li a.fly
    {
        background: rgb(136, 136, 136);
    }
    #flyout li:hover
    {
        position: relative;
    }
    #flyout li a:hover
    {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        position: relative;
        background-color: rgb(238, 102, 0);
    }
    #flyout li:hover > a
    {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background-color: rgb(238, 102, 0);
    }
    #flyout ul li a
    {
        background: rgb(170, 170, 170);
    }
    #flyout ul li a.fly
    {
        background: rgb(170, 170, 170);
    }
    #flyout ul ul li a
    {
        background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    }
    #flyout ul ul li a.fly
    {
        background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    }
    #flyout ul ul ul li a
    {
        background: rgb(221, 221, 221);
    }
    #flyout li a.current
    {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background-color: rgb(204, 68, 0);
    }
    #flyout ul li a.current
    {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background-color: rgb(204, 68, 0);
    }
    #flyout ul ul li a.current
    {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background-color: rgb(204, 68, 0);
    }
    #flyout ul ul ul li a.current
    {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background-color: rgb(204, 68, 0);
    }
    #flyout :hover ul
    {
        left: -160px;
    }
    #flyout :hover ul :hover ul
    {
        left: -160px;
    }
    #flyout :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul
    {
        left: -120px;
    }
    #flyout :hover ul ul
    {
        left: -9999px;
    }
    #flyout :hover ul :hover ul ul
    {
        left: -9999px;
    }
    #flyout ul li:hover > a
    {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background-color: rgb(238, 102, 0);
    }
    #flyout ul ul li:hover > a
    {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background-color: rgb(238, 102, 0);
    }
</style>
<div>
    <ul id="flyout">
        <li><a class="fly" href="/globalop/pages/CatPage.aspx"><b>category</b><!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
            <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#url"><b>sub category</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#url"><b>sub category</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#url"><b>sub category</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#url"><b>sub category</b></a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#url"><b>sub category</b></a></li>
            </ul>
            <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
        </li>
        <li><a class="fly" href="/globalop/pages/CatPage.aspx"><b>category</b><!--[if gte IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->
            <!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#url"><b>sub category</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#url"><b>sub category</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#url"><b>sub category</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#url"><b>sub category</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#url"><b>sub category</b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#url"><b>sub category</b></a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#url"><b>sub category</b></a></li>
            </ul>
            <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]-->
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

on top of all that I get a very long scroll bar in the end of the page which the original example (from which the flyout menu code was taken) did not show.

But I just want to understand why the "main" div is not getting the height of the menu's div and it shows height = 0.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of your code for convenience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi actually you have given the float to the child div's and not clear your parent div so always clear parent div if you are using floating in the child div's....

so now your main div is cleared and its taking his height properly.

Here is the fiddle of your updated HTML and css code http://jsfiddle.net/Y6KMN/1/

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent like half a night on this. This surely solves this issue. Do you have any idea why do I get this extremely long horizontal scrollbar (which exsposes the subcategories elements at its left end)? I can put 'overflow: hidden;" to the child's div, but then I can see only elements which are visual inside the parent div (and the 'main' div height is only as high as the category elements, so I can't see the subcategory elements).

Comment: can you show me the example on fiddle that would be easier for me to find out the bug....

Answer (score 0):

thats because your flyoutmenu has the property `float:right;`

so this element is not in the flow anymore and there has no height for the parent element.

put this after your flyoutmenu to tell the browser to cancel the float and continue the normal way.

`<div style="clear:both;"></div>`

Edit: Full markup

```
<body>
    <form id="formMaster" runat="server">
    <div id="header">
        bla bla
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div>
            <ucCatMenu:MenuControl ID="CatMenu" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        bla bla
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use inherit to solve ur problem like this one

```
<div class="div1" style="width:inherit; height:inherit">
```

it's sample use it on your convenience ... :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried it, but without clearing after the child div it didn't work for some reason. I'll try and play with it a little to understand this inherit attribute better. Thanks a lot.